# Synonyms for "use" with positive conntotion?

Tags: single-word-requests

> "First, we will look into the representations of the mind as
> multifaceted and beautiful, examining how Moore **[uses]** these
> aesthetics to challenge notions that the mind is solely useful for its
> logical reasoning, and endorse the duality of creativity and
> rationality."

I would like to replace the use of "use" in this sentence with something more sophisticated. I want to say that Moore exploits it (but with a positive connotation), or "profiter de" (in French) from these representations to "challenge...".

Comment: *A list of synonyms would be much appreciated* You're expected to have found a list of synonyms yourself, perhaps by consulting a thesaurus, before asking your question.  And then, in your question, to explain why none of them quite satisfies your purpose.

Comment: I removed that request. Can you tell us what you mean by 'sophistication', and, more importantly, why 'use' doesn't quite cut it?

Comment: I provided "exploited", that's the closest word I could find. "Manipulated" seems to have more of a negative connotation. "Employ" is too neutral. I would like a positive connotation word please. "Use" doesn't convey the sense that she's using it *expertly* to convey her further ideas; the verb doesn't seem strong enough and doesn't showcase how she's *cleverly* 'used' these techniques.

Comment: Adopting complicated synonyms to sound more sophisticated is rarely successful.

Comment: I agree, but in this case, I would like to avoid repetition of "use" as well.

Comment: For your purposes, I'd exploit the startling quality of *exploits* (meaning 'uses shrewdly' and not strictly negative), because Moore reverses something here. *Employs*, *inverts* or *repurposes* may also work.

Comment: Explores, challenges, questions, investigates, contemplates, or deconstructs are [the sort of terms used for this kind of writing](https://canopycanopycanopy.com/contents/international_art_english).

Comment: @StuartF Strong verbs there.

Comment: _Exploitation_ is the nominalization of _exploit_, if you're determined to use a noun. But _exploit_ can be interpreted as bad behavior. Though in this context, it's not, really, as long as it doesn't involve outright plagiarism (and even then, Warhol got away with it). Ars longa, vita brevis.

Comment: Ooh, *leverages* would be perfect here, except verbing this noun doesn’t always go over well with everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leverage) defines "leverage" as:

> 2 : to use for gain : EXPLOIT 
> shamelessly *leverage* the system to their advantage
> —Alexander Wolff

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/leverage) defines it as:

> 5 to use (a quality or advantage) to obtain a desired effect or result: 
> *She was able to leverage her travel experience and her gift for languages to get a job as a translator.*

Answer (score 1):

utilize

> verb : to make use of : turn to practical use or account

> I'm a great person for utilizing waste power — Robert Frost

source: [www.merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com)

Answer (score 0):

You could say that Moore **draws on** the aesthetics. [TfD defines it as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/draw+on)

> To access and use a helpful resource.

[Cambridge gives a more specific definition:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/draw-on)

> to use information or your knowledge of something to help you do something